# Theorem 46.8 Munkres Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness

In the proof of Theorem 46.8 Munkres Topology following is claimed (not exact copy but exact interpretation)

> If A is any compact subset of a metric space Y and V is any  open subset of Y containing A then there is a $\epsilon>0 $ such that the $\epsilon-$neighborhood of A is contained in V.

The mentioned claim is true provided $d(A, X-V) >0$ is positive. 1- But how to prove that? And 2- how any open set containing a compact set is a proper superset?

Comment: Are there more assumptions? Consider $Y = [0,1] \cup [2, 3]$ as a metric space with the usual metric. Let $A = [0,1]$, and let $V = [0,1]$, which is open in $Y$. There is no $\epsilon$-neighborhood.

Comment: @DuduBob: Yes, there is: $[0,1]$ is its own $\epsilon$-nbhd for every positive $\epsilon\le 1$, assuming that we’re talking about the usual metric.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah, you are right. I confused myself.

Comment: The function $f:A\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto d(x,X\setminus V)$ is a continuous function on a compact set, so it attains its minimum at some point $x\in A$, and that minimum is positive.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, yes but I don't know how that minimum it must be positive.

Comment: @L.G.: Sure you do: $d(x,X\setminus V)>0$ for each $x\in A$ simply because $X\setminus V$ is a closed set disjoint from $A$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott X is metric, A and X-V are closed and X is normal. But why that two disjoint neighborhoods of A and X-V, their closures are still disjoint?

Comment: @L.G.: I didn’t say any such thing. Let $F=X\setminus V$. $F$ is a closed set, and $x\notin F$, so $d(x,F)>0$. If you’ve never proved this, you should do so now.

Comment: What do you mean by question 2: "how any open set containing a compact set is a proper superset"? How does it link to this theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Brian M. Scott stated, the function $f: A \to \mathbb R$ sending $x$ to $d(x, Y \setminus V)$ is continuous on $A$ and $A$ is compact, so $f$ attains its minimum on $A$, at say $x \in A$. But if $d(x, Y \setminus V) = 0$, this means there exists a sequence of elements $\{y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in $Y \setminus V$ satisfying $d(x,y_n) \to 0$. Since $Y \setminus V$ is closed, this implies $x \in Y \setminus V$, a contradiction since $A \subseteq V$. Therefore, we can pick $\varepsilon = \frac{d(x,Y \setminus V)}2$ to get an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood $U$ of $A$ contained in $V$. By definition, $d(U, Y \setminus V) = \frac{d(x, Y \setminus V)}2 > 0$, so $U$ is contained in $V$.

You won't be able to prove that $A \subsetneq U$ because it's not true in some cases. Take the example of $Y$ finite and discrete; $\varepsilon$-neighborhoods of $A$ are just $A$ for $\varepsilon$ small enough (smaller than any distance between any two distinct points, for example).

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

A direct proof which does not relyy on the continuity of the distance function (a handy fact though that is..):

If $A \subseteq V$ for each $a \in A$ find $r_a>0$ such that $B(a,2r_a) \subseteq V$ (by openness of $V$ and the fact that $a \in A$ implies $a \in V$).

By compactness of $A$ there are finitely many $a_1, \ldots a_n \in A$ so that

$$A \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n B(a_i, r_{a_i})$$

and define $r=\min_{i=1}^n r_{a_i} >0$.

If now $x$ in $U(A,r)$ there is some $a \in A$ such that $d(x,a) < r$. This $a$ lies in some $B(a_i, r_{a_i})$ so that $d(x,r_{a_i}) \le d(x,a) + d(a,a_i) < r + r_{a_i} < 2r_{a_i}$ and so $x \in B(a_i, 2r_{a_i}) \subseteq V$. This shows that $U(a,r) \subseteq V$ as required.